# The proper way to use lstrip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to form a python-dict of attributes which I've got via odbc from MS SQL. Some of the ites contain whitespaces or \t (TAB) which I am willing to get rid of. However, the most (for me) natural way of doing this doesn't seem to function:

```
    items = [a, b, c, d]
    cursor.execute('SELECT '+query_text+' FROM DEV.blabla')
    list_attr_data = {}
    for each_item in items:
        list_attr_data[each_item] = []
    for row in cursor:
        for x in range(len(items)):
            a = row[x].lstrip()
            list_attr_data[items[x]].append(a)
```

When printing a, I can see that a has no \t or other unwished signs, but when I print the whole dict `list_attr_data`, I can see that the it has all of them again.

What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish the task in the most elegant way?

Comment: `lstrip` removes leading whitespace. Is it *leading* whitespace that you are trying to remove?

Comment: Your code is *appending* a to each element of `list_attr_data`. So after your loop has run, each element will contain both the original values and the stripped ones.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using strip() instead of lstrip()